# How to Use Set.toArray() for sorting Strings?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

I've found many answers to converting a Set to an ArrayList, but none of it really helps my problem. I have a program here that reads from a file.txt and determines how similar sentences are to each other using a Jaccard Similarity Matrix. Contents in the file.txt are as follows:

> The cat in the hat 
>  The cat sat on the mat 
>  Pigs in a
>   blanket

I then have a for loop that pairs each char on each line with the adjacent char and puts them in a HashSet to ensure uniqueness. Like so:

> [ c, in,  h,  i, t , n , at, Th,  t, th, ha, e , he, ca] 
>  [ c, t ,
>   m, sa,  o, n , at,  s, Th,  t, th, ma, e , he, ca, on] 
>  [ a,  b,
>   in,  i, bl, gs, s , an, et, n , la, Pi, ke, nk, ig, a ]

My problem now is getting the pairs of chars out of the Set and into an ArrayList to be sorted and then each pair from a line compared to another pair of chars on another line using String.equals() for the Jaccard formula: J = number of matches / unique pairs. I have a single Set that is recycled after its filled with the first line.

```
    HashSet<String> shingleTrimSet = new HashSet<String>();
    List<String> shingleArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("\nSorted Shingles:");

    for(int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++){
        shingleTrimSet.clear();

        for(int idx = 0, jdx = 1; idx+1 < lines[i].length(); idx++, jdx++){
            shingleTrimSet.add( lines[i].substring( idx, jdx+1 ) );
        }
        shingleTrimSet.toArray( new String[shingleTrimSet.size()] );

    }
```

shingleTrimSet.toArray( new String[shingleTrimSet.size()] ) works in this scenario, but I don't know how to use it for something else later. How do I know what ArrayList the Set has been placed into? Its seems to not have a variable name.

Comment: new String[shingleTrimSet.size()]   why did you not bind this to a variable?

Comment: You could store the result of `toArray` in a variable....

Comment: `toArray()` returns an array of the type specified by the parameter, you need to assign it to a variable. `String[] myArray = shingleTrimSet.toArray( new String[shingleTrimSet.size()] );`

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList has another constructor that takes a Java Collections subclass. So you can do `shingleArrayList = new ArrayList<>(shingleTrimSet)`

If you just want to sort the set, you can use `Collections.sort` or just use a TreeSet which keeps it elements sorted by their natural order.

Comment: You can't use `Collections.sort` on a set.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have a variable name because you didn't give it one?

```
String[] array = shingleTrimSet.toArray( new String[shingleTrimSet.size()] );
```

But that's not an `ArrayList`, it's an array.  You could do

```
shingleArrayList.addAll(shingleTrimSet);
```

which would also work without a copy.

Comment: This works. I tried `List.add( set )` but it kept giving me errors.

Comment: No, you'd need `addAll`, not `add`.

Answer (score 0):

shingleTrimSet.toArray( new String[shingleTrimSet.size()] );

If you pass directly the new array and you do not reference it anymore... how would you get it after that?

try to do this:

```
String newString = new String[shingleTrimSet.size()]; and then
shingleTrimSet.toArray( newString );
```